# My SQL query gives Unknown column 'bisns.attribute_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

This code and it's associated db tables are in use on another site and work perfectly. However when i used it on another site i get an error.
I have checked the table and the column attribute_id does exist.

```
SELECT bisns.product_id, pd.products_name, COUNT(*) AS num_subscribers, p.products_type,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', IFNULL(bisns.attribute_id, 'attribute_id'), pov.products_options_values_name, IFNULL(pwas.quantity, 'quantity'), IFNULL(bisns.customer_id, 'customer_id'), bisns.name, bisns.email_address)) as attributes, COUNT(DISTINCT bisns.product_id) as product_count_distinct, COUNT(DISTINCT bisns.attribute_id) as attribute_count_distinct, COUNT(bisns.attribute_id) as attribute_count,p.products_quantity AS current_stock, cd.categories_name
        FROM
            " . TABLE_BACK_IN_STOCK_NOTIFICATION_SUBSCRIPTIONS . " bisns
        LEFT JOIN
            " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd
        ON
            (pd.products_id = bisns.product_id
        AND
            pd.language_id = '" . $_SESSION['languages_id'] . "')
        LEFT JOIN
            " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p
        ON
            p.products_id = pd.products_id
        LEFT JOIN 
            " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd 
        ON 
            (p.master_categories_id = cd.categories_id
        AND
            cd.language_id = '" . $_SESSION['languages_id'] . "')
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " pa 
        ON pa.products_attributes_id  = bisns.attribute_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_OPTIONS . " po 
        ON pa.options_id = po.products_options_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_OPTIONS_VALUES . " pov 
        ON pa.options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_WITH_ATTRIBUTES_STOCK . " pwas 
        ON pa.products_attributes_id = pwas.stock_attributes 
        WHERE
            1 = 1
        GROUP BY
            bisns.product_id"
```

Can anyone come up with a reason why this query would be throwing an error and how i can resolve it because it's got me beat.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to check if there is a difference for the lower and upper cases. Depending on the settings, MySQL will or will not check for an exact match for the cases.

The second thing would be to print the final result of the above sql string after the substitutions are done to make sure that everything is OK.

Finally, you can try to run the final query directly in the MySQL Workbench to see what could be the error.